# CakePHP 2.4.1 $this->webroot gives / and not /app/webroot

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I've inherited a CakePHP 2.4.1 project and I don't want to use all the html, css, script helpers as it is make the app more dependent on CakePHP if we ever wanted to change frameworks, but when I try to load scripts, styles, images using

```
<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>css/app.min.css
```

but that produces a URL of

```
http://example.com/app.min.css
```

$this->webroot just returns /, I'm not very familiar with CakePHP yet.  Is there a configuration setting or something that is set that is changing this?  My vhosts file is pointed at webroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Webroot" is the directory that is accessible to the public. It contains all of your asset elements, etc, it should look like:

```
-- webroot
| -- assets
    | -- css
    | -- js
    | -- img
| -- index.php
//etc
```

So when you run `$this->webroot` you are getting the path to your public directory. This assumes that all asset files will reside in this directory.

In the event that this has been modified, simply open up the `index.php` of your application and find this line:

```
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'MY_WEBROOT_DIR');
```

And change `MY_WEBROOT_DIR` to the actual name of your public directory as it resides `within your CakePHP Application`